# RTC in MSP430 microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, c, programming, msp430, rtc

I'm trying to generate a 15 minutes alarm using RTC in MSP430F5438A microcontroller from Texas Instruments. What values should I put in the Interrupt registers. I have tried putting 0x95 in RTCAMIN register but it generates an interrupt at 15 min, 1 hour 15 minutes, 2 hours 15 minutes, and so on. I want the interrupt at 15 min and only one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the interrupt at 15 minutes already using 0x95 (meaning you are using the BCD format instead of hex, I presume).  So you just want to disable the additional alarms at 1:15, 2:15, etc.

Set RTCAMIN to 0x00 as the first thing in your Interrupt Service Routine for the alarm to clear the alarm enable (AE) bit and thus set it up as a simple one-shot.

Comment: Yes I'm using BCD format. I read somewhere that the interrupts are automatically cleared once serviced.

Comment: @Jayesh The interrupt is definitely getting cleared, like you said, otherwise you wouldn't be getting multiple interrupts.  But that is independent of whether future alarms are enabled.  If you *desired* multiple interrupts, you'd need both conditions.  By clearing AE in your ISR, you ensure it only happens once.